# How to get $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my magento application created a phtml page in template/page/ folder..

Here displayed a products...Then there is a need for displaying

```
$this->getAddToCartUrl($product)
```

But it return null value...that means no value returned it.....

How can i get it in my phtml page .......

This is the html code:

```
<input id="url_<?php echo $_iterator;?>" name="url_$_iterator;" type="text" value="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>">
```

anyboady have any solution....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you try this....

```
 <?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>
```

Just try this instead of this `$this->getAddToCartUrl($product)`

Comment: you don't just define your template as 'catalog/product_list'

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to call `getAddToCartUrl` your Block class must be inherit from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` (in the layout declaration)

Is it the case ?